# ui-router "The transition was ignored" during state transition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I want to set a general error handler for certain states of my app like `main.*` and want to redirect user to a general error page if any of state `resolves` are failed.

I set the following error handler:

```
  $transitions.onError({to: "main.*"}, function (trans) {                   
       $state.go("transition-error")
  });
```

but If I click on a link say `<a ui-sref="main.profile"> profile </a>`, and transition occurs successfully and I click on that link for the second time, my error handler gets executed with an error message of: `"The transition was ignored"`, How can I prevent my error handler to be executed when there is such error? Why am I receiving this error?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error details can be retrieved from the transition using  `trans.error()`.  The value is a `Rejection` object.  In your `onError` handler, check the type of the rejection.  For example, you could choose to redirect only if the reject type is "ERROR":

```
$transitions.onError({to: "main.*"}, function (trans) {                   
   var rejection = trans.error();
   if (rejection.type === RejectType.ERROR) { // === 6
     $state.go("transition-error");
   }
});
```

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.rejection.html#type

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/enums/transition.rejecttype.html#error

Comment: I've updated the documentation to better reflect this information.  It will be available when the next version of ui-router is released.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you very much, I somewhat the same approach: `if (transitionError.type !== 5)
                    $state.go("main.transition-error")`